# Store value from JSON to NSUserDefaults and then call

Tags: ios, json, swift2, nsuserdefaults

Please help me. I have a post request, which return value. I store it in NSUserDefaults, and use as parameter to function on another ViewController. Value that i store - is a group ID for logging user.
But my function fires earlier, then NSUserDefaults called.
So, code

```
// LoginViewController

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in           
        if error != nil {
           print("error=\(error)")
        }
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJson = json {
                let resultValue:String = parseJson["status"] as! String
                let resultValue2:String = parseJson["id"] as! String
                    if(resultValue == "Success") {
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLogin")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(resultValue2, forKey: "groupID")

                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Then i call it for another POST request, as parameter to func

```
let groupID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("groupID")!
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    getLatestTasks(groupID as! String)
```

First time it works perfect, but if i log out, and login again - value still old.

Comment: Under let groupID, what happens when you remove NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize().  Also, when are you calling this POST request?

Comment: The same. synchronize does not change situation )

Comment: Three side notes: 1) It's bad habit (and the app will crash) just to print the error and proceed as there were no error. 2) Never use `synchronize()` while reading user defaults. Actually forcing `synchronize()` is not needed at all  3) Use `setObject:forKey / stringForKey:` for `String`type  rather than `setValue:forKey / valueForKey:`

Comment: vadian, Thanks. Make some changes. But question still open.

Comment: You may want to update your question, removing the `synchronize` code. Additionally, preferences are no safe place to save protected user data.

Comment: So, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are aware that the data task is asynchronous, and that calling whatever function contains the code in your first snippet does not guarantee that the values will have been received and stored by the time it returns? Give us more details as to when/how the two snippets are called. Also, add logs to your completion handler to check what you actually receive and whether the data is actually saved.